# Active Directory: Can't login from one workstation

Tags: active-directory, domain, login

here is my problem:

I recently created a new Active Directory Domain (Windows Server 2008 R2), and add users to the domain. Then I migrated each computers  to the new domain, log off, and then log on as NEWDOMAIN\Username. That worked for each computers, except one: when I changed the domain, it prompted "Welcome to domain NEWDOMAIN" (as expected), and I can now see the computer registered as an AD Object. I log off, and login as NEWDOMAIN\Username but it says that User Profile Service can't load the profile. I am just able to connect via NEWDOMAIN\Admin.

I retried the manipulation a couple of time on that computer and no results. So every user is able to connect to any computer except that one, so I guess this is a machine-specific issue. This machine runs Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

Reboot the computer, log on as NEWDOMAIN\Administrator. Go to C:\Users and rename the user profile folder (if it exists). If the problem persists remove the computer from the domain and rejoin.

Comment: Good answer. This is sort of thing is often caused by bad permissions on C:\users so starting with a fresh/empty c:\users fixes it.